# Unable to connect to any of the specific MySQL hosts with AWS Lambda to RDS MySQL

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

I have an `AWS Lambda` function for an API.  I have a test function inside of the API that returns a "Success" string so I know that I can hit the API from my machine (Postman).

The Lambda API is inside of my VPC.  I have public and private subnets.  The API is living in the public subnets.  I also have a RDS database that's living in the private subnets.  I can connect to the database through a Bastion host so I know the database is connected and working.

When I try an API call that connects to the database, I can see an error in `CloudWatch` that says:

> [Error] Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction: Unknown error responding to request: MySqlException:
>       MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one matching element

There's a lot of references to that error message that talks about the Linq `SingleOrDefault()` method, but I don't have any references to that method.

I think that error has something to do with the security groups.  I have an RDS security group that has an inbound rule on port 3306 from my internal VPC ip addresses.

The security group for my Lambda function should be ok since I can successfully hit the test route.

Finally, I tried connecting to the database through the API in debug on my machine and I get an error `"The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found"`

Does anyone have any other ideas or places to look?

Comment: Try to open 3306 to all for troubleshooting?

Comment: are you using nat gateway or  nat instance ?

Comment: @aviboy2006 I'm not using either.  I don't need to initiate traffic to the internet from the private subnets, only to the Lambda living in the public subnets.

Comment: Allowing inbound traffic on DB from internet is not recommended and should always be avoided you added this ? this is new error you getting ?

Comment: It's not a new error.  I just dug into the CloudWatch details a little more.  I'm not allowing inbound traffic on DB.  Inbound rules are 10.0.* and the SG from Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your this setting is enable or not for RDS Security group ?

[image: Inbound RDS Security Group]

[image: Outbound RDS Security Group]

**Disclaimer** :  Allowing inbound traffic on DB from internet is not recommended and should always be avoided

Comment: My inbound rules are TCP 3306 for my VPC IP addresses and for the SG for my Lambda function.  Outbound rules are all traffic.

Comment: you are having separate SG for both RDS and Lambda ?

Comment: Please add a disclaimer in the answer. Allowing inbound traffic on DB from internet is not recommended and should always be avoided. It should have proper sourceIP/ SG values.

Comment: @aviboy2006 I have seperate SG for Lambda and RDS.  Lambda inbound is from my local machine for testing and the IP of the web server.  Outbound is all traffic.

Comment: have u assigned lambda two subnet one is lambda specfic and one for RDS specific   ?

Comment: Did you ever fiind the solution to this? I am running into same issue at the moment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My RDS database (that I was trying to connect to and read from using AWS Lambda) was also a MySQL database.

When I tested the Lambda function I was getting 'Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts' (after waiting -- like it was timing-out).

I reviewed the answer from @aviboy2006, which helped me.  I tried all the Security Group rules shown in that answer.  I found I was able to successfully connect-to and read from the RDS MySQL database when I defined both an Inbound and Outbound rule for the associated VPC Security Group as

```
Type: MYSQL/Aurora
Protocol: TCP
Port Range: 3306
Source: Custom: 0.0.0.0/0
```

[image]